# PHP - Create new file containing all lines from file1 that do not contain any of the text from lines in file2

Tags: php

I've read a load of posts on StackExchange but can't find exactly what I need. Note: this is not just about removing duplicates. I need to go through File1.csv and create a new file - Results.csv - with every line it contains that doesn't contain a line from File2.txt.

File1.csv contains personal details and email addresses, 1 per line:

```
"mr","Happy","Man","mrhappy@example.com"
"mr","Sad","Man","mrsad@example.com"
"mr","Grumpy","Man","mrgrumpy@example.com"
"mr","Strong","Man","mrstrong@example.com"
```

File2.txt contains email addresses, 1 per line:

```
mrhappy@example.com
mrsomeoneelse@example.com
mrsomeoneelse2@example.com
```

Expected result: Results.csv should contain:

```
"mr","Sad","Man","mrsad@example.com"
"mr","Grumpy","Man","mrgrumpy@example.com"
"mr","Strong","Man","mrstrong@example.com"
```

Confusingly, the code I have works as expected when File2.txt contains a single line. But when it contains more than one line Results.txt contains all lines from File1.csv (including lines that should have been removed) and repeats those lines multiple times (as many times as there are lines in File2.txt). I've got a feeling I'm close but I can't figure it out.

My code:

```
<?php
$to_be_searched = "File1.csv";

$items_to_catch = file("File2.txt");

// create empty array to store lines we want to keep - i.e. lines that dont contain emails we're checking for
$good_lines = array();

// open $to_be_searched
$handle = fopen($to_be_searched, "r");
if ($handle) {
  // go line by line until end of file
  while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    // check if line contains any items from $items_to_catch
    foreach($items_to_catch as $key => $value) {
      if(strpos($line, $value) === false) {
        // email wasn't found on the line so we want this line in the results file, therefore add to $good_lines array
        $good_lines[] = $line;
      } 
    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
} else {
  echo "Couldn't open " . $to_be_searched;
  exit();
}

// write $array_of_good_lines into new file
$new_file = "Results.csv";
foreach($good_lines as $key => $value) {
    file_put_contents($new_file, $value, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to replace `foreach($items_to_catch as $key => $value) {` for `foreach($items_to_catch as $value) {`

Comment: @FelippeDuarte thanks, but no, that doesn't work. i can't see how it relates to the problem as described either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working currently because in your foreach, you're adding the same line multiple times to `$good_lines`.

To fix this, you can add a flag variable to your loop.

```
while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
    // Declare our flag variable as false by default
    $found = false;

    // Loop through each item to see if the email has been found
    foreach($items_to_catch as $key => $value) {
        // If the email was found, stop looping in the second file
        if(strpos($line, $value) !== false){
            $found = true;
            break;
        } 
    }

    // If the email was not found in the second file, add it to the good_lines array
    if(!$found)
        $good_lines[] = $line;
}
```

### Update

Beside the loop, you have another problem when you're reading the `File2.txt`, since it's adding the line breaks into the string, therefore, when you compare the string later on with `strpos`, it's not working. To fix that:

```
$items_to_catch = file("File2.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

This is the var_dump of the $items_to_catch without the flag:

```
array (size=3)
    0 => string 'mrhappy@example.com
    ' (length=20)
    1 => string 'mrsomeoneelse@example.com
    ' (length=26)
    2 => string 'mrsomeoneelse2@example.com
    ' (length=27)
```

This is the var_dump of the $items_to_catch with the flag:

```
array (size=3)
    0 => string 'mrhappy@example.com' (length=19)
    1 => string 'mrsomeoneelse@example.com' (length=25)
    2 => string 'mrsomeoneelse2@example.com' (length=26)
```

Notice the extra character in each of the emails, which is the line break.

Comment: that's solved the repeated lines problem but $good_lines still contains all lines from File1.csv when File2.txt contains more than 1 line. If File2.txt contains only 1 line - e.g. only mrhappy@example.com - then Results.csv contains the expected lines as in the question. In other words, when $items_to_catch array contains 1 value result is as expected; but if $items_to_catch array contains more than 1 value Results.csv is simply an exact copy of File1.csv and contains lines that should not be there. Why is this?

Comment: Can you try to var_dump the $items_to_catch for me when you have multiple lines on the file2.txt? I think it's taking all the lines as one big string, therefore, it can't find any emails.

Comment: @penname I've found the problem, and updated my answer. The problem was the line break after each email. You just have to update the $items_to_catch to add the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag when you call the file function.

Comment: Thank you! It works perfectly. Can I ask 2 questions: (1) about your first fix, why did my original `if(strpos($line, $value) === false) {$good_lines[] = $line;}` not work? I thought that because the add to array instruction was contained in an if statement it should run only IF strpos() returned false (i.e. string was NOT found), and if string was found then it should not run... Why is this not correct? (2) What led you to find that FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES was needed? Did you just do var_dump() and notice it looked wrong? Again, thanks so much! Will mark your answer accepted.

Comment: @penname For your 1st question, your if case is not working because you're comparing the the line with each line of the file 2. So, if you think about it like how the computer reads it, you'll understand quite easily. For example, my file one has A B C. My file two has B and C. In my first loop, A will be added 2 times because A is not equal to B (add one). then A is not equal to C, add another time. Then for B. B is equal to B, so we don't add. But then, B is not equal to C, so we add again. Which is why you need a flag to check all the file 2 before deciding to add or not.

Comment: @penname Oops, for your 2nd question, yes I did a var_dump and I noticed the string was on two lines.

Answer (score 1):

`file()` returns each line of the file *including the terminal line ending*. If you look at the `$items_to_catch` using [Symfony's VarDumper component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper/introduction.html) you'll see it looks like:

```
array:3 [
   0 => "mrhappy@example.com\n"
   1 => "mrsomeoneelse@example.com\n"
   2 => "mrsomeoneelse2@example.com\n"
]
```

Which isn't what you want, since your later comparison *does not* include the terminal line ending. As an aside, Symfony's VarDumper component is orders of magnitude better than `print_r` and `var_dump`: I *highly* recommend composing it into your projects.

So, trim away the terminal new lines with:

```
$items_to_catch = array_map('trim', file('File2.txt'));
```

A minimal working example:

```
$excludedLinesWithTheseEmails = array_map('trim', file('File2.txt'));

$out = fopen('Results.csv', 'w') or die('Cannot open Results.csv');
$in = fopen('File1.csv', 'r') or die('Cannot open File1.csv');
while (false !== ($row = fgetcsv($in))) {
    if (! in_array($row[3], $excludedLinesWithTheseEmails)) {
        fputcsv($out, $row);
    }
}
fclose($out);
fclose($in);
```

Comment: Thank you. I marked Chin Leung's answer as accepted because I read it first but your solution is brilliant and so much shorter than mine. Can I ask, what did you use to display `0 => "mrhappy@example.com\n"` with the `\n`. I used print_r and var_dump on the command line but I didn't notice the `\n`. EDIT: also, would you mind explaining `(false !== ($row = fgetcsv($in)))` - how can you put the check for "is not exactly false" first?

Comment: @penname You can always change the accepted answer if one comes along that better fits your needs. So long as you've accepted the answer that *best* answers *your* question, I'm happy. :)

Comment: @penname Placing the constant `false` on the left is a programming style called [Yoda conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions). In languages like PHP that allow assignment in a conditional block, Yoda conditions prevent an accidental assignment where comparison was intended.